# style attribute inside html:text expression error

Tags: java, jsp, styles, struts, scriptlet

I have the following tag:

```jsp
<html:text styleClass="span2" property="groupManagerId" styleId="groupManagerId" maxlength="19" size="10" readonly="" />
```

which works correctly. When I add a `style` attribute:

```jsp
<html:text styleClass="span2" style="display:<%=(""+FVConstants.NORMAL).equalsIgnoreCase(groupData.getGroupType())?"none":" "%>;" property="groupManagerId" styleId="groupManagerId" maxlength="19" size="10" readonly="" />
```

I get the following error:

```java
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /pages/POS0085_group_modify.jsp(95,61) Unterminated &lt;html:text tag
```

I have the same attribute under  `label` and `div` tags and it works correctly. I changed to

```jsp
 <%String displayValue=(""+FVConstants.NORMAL).equalsIgnoreCase(groupData.getGroupType())?"none":" ";
                                String displayAttr="display:"+displayValue; %>
```

and

```
<html:text styleClass="span2" style="display:<%=displayValue%>" property="groupManagerId" styleId="groupManagerId" maxlength="19" size="10" readonly="" />
```

and it works. What is wrong with the first attempt? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Last I checked, `<%=(""+FVConstants.NORMAL).equalsIgnoreCase(groupData.getGroupType())?"none":" "%>` was not a valid css value for the display style. I think you might be missing some background information (and a tag maybe) in your post. What processes that code?

Comment: You cannot nest scriptlets like that. The better way would be to set a value accessible via JSP EL and use either a recent container, for the html-el tags.

Comment: @jdwire Correct, but that's not what the error is indicating--it's a JSP tag issue, not a CSS issue.

Comment: @DaveNewton I knew that it was some other language that would be processed server-side, but the question does not mention any language except html, and the OP would probably get a faster answer if the language was stated in the question and one of the tags. Thanks for making this clear to others though.

Answer (score 0):

This error often happened when beginners trying to use the `?` operator to evaluate to string. The evaluated expression should be surrounded with the brackets like that

```
<html:text styleClass="span2" style="display:<%=((""+FVConstants.NORMAL).equalsIgnoreCase(groupData.getGroupType())?"none":" ")%>;" property="groupManagerId" styleId="groupManagerId" maxlength="19" size="10" readonly="" />
```